# Archival stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Good morning everyone, I am trying to figure out how to move certain rows from one table to another. Here is the kicker; each row in this active table has a date format of the letter D with yyyymmdd (for example today would be D20161020). What I am trying to do is to take all rows from the previous month (for example D201609##) and move them to an archive table (copy then remove the copied rows ).

My plan and thinking is to keep the current data lean to be as quick as possible. And yes I am using indexes, I just do not want the table to get that big. :) Each day, I import 3000+ records into that table. For slimness, I am referring by record ID to the master record table. Essentially, this table has a RecID Foreign Key to the master record table RecID and the date in that format Dyyyymmdd. I place the count for that date into the corresponding records.

Here is the other thing, I am looking to only keep the current month's data in the active table.

I plan to keep the archive tables by year, i.e 2016counts, 2017counts which will hold that year's data.

I figure for the yearly archive table, I can simply create a procedure that will copy all the data from the current archive table to the year archive and then truncate that active table. Or rename the table and just re-create a blank table like it since the active archive table will have nothing in it except for the first column which is a correlated record ID from a master table of records.

Comment: please explain with some sample data and show final output

Comment: Did you really mean to move "columns"? Don't you mean you want to move "rows"?

Comment: @TT. i made that assumption, hopefully it was the correct assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample that contains most of what you'll need to do what you are after. Hopefully the comments are self explanatory as to what each step is doing. The below code is re-runnable, so you can view the output it generates and tweak it to test different variations.

```
CREATE TABLE #Main ( DateVal NVARCHAR(15) -- should be a date really!!!
                     )

CREATE TABLE #Archive ( DateVal NVARCHAR(15) -- should be a date really!!!
                        )

INSERT  INTO #Main
        ( DateVal
        )
        SELECT  'D20161001'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'D20161002'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'D20161003'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'D20161004'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'D20160913'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'D20160911'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'D20161007'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'D20160901'

-- values as they are
SELECT  DateVal
FROM    #Main

-- values with dates formatted from values and month extracted
SELECT  DateVal ,
        RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DateSection ,
        CAST(RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DATE) ConvertedToDate ,
        DATEPART(MONTH, ( CAST(RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DATE) )) MonthPart
FROM    #Main

-- values not in current month - to archive
SELECT  DateVal ,
        RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DateSection ,
        CAST(RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DATE) ConvertedToDate ,
        DATEPART(MONTH, ( CAST(RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DATE) )) MonthPart
FROM    #Main
WHERE   DATEPART(MONTH, ( CAST(RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DATE) )) < DATEPART(MONTH,
                                                              GETDATE())

-- insert the archived records
INSERT  INTO #Archive
        ( DateVal
        )
        SELECT  DateVal
        FROM    #Main
        WHERE   DATEPART(MONTH, ( CAST(RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DATE) )) < DATEPART(MONTH,
                                                              GETDATE())

-- delete the archived records
DELETE  #Main
WHERE   DATEPART(MONTH, ( CAST(RIGHT(DateVal, 8) AS DATE) )) < DATEPART(MONTH,
                                                              GETDATE())

-- see what's archived
SELECT  *
FROM    #Archive

-- see what's active
SELECT  *
FROM    #Main

DROP TABLE #Main
DROP TABLE #Archive
```

Comment: I will give this a shot in a little while today, it looks similar to what I am trying to do, may need some tweaking to dynamically pull in last months'/years dates. I'll get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: I ended up using a dynamic query built into a stored proc. What I need to do now is using Dynamic SQL remove the records from the previous month but I have to determine the month and year by calculating them. I like your use of the temp table. To see the proc, go to https://forums.asp.net/post/6091304.aspx

Comment: that link doesn't work for me, if you have a follow up question ask another question or edit this question as long as the question doesn't change too much so my answer doesn't make sense.