# Follow up - Archival Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Ok, the previous thread I started was [Archival stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173934/archival-stored-procedures) but this is a follow up question to that. What I have is a working stored procedure that makes an exact copy of the active database, however when I want to remove the old columns from the previous month, the procedure blows up right there with an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'D201609__'.

Here is the code from the full proc:

```
declare @tablename varchar(500)
declare @sql varchar(5000)
declare @idname varchar(50)
declare @tablearchive varchar(500)
declare @lastmonth nvarchar(MAX)

SET @lastmonth = 'D' + cast(year(getdate()) as char(4)) + right('0' + cast(month(getdate())-1 as varchar), 2) + '__'
--Select all the tables which you want to make in archive

declare tableCursor cursor FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE table_name = 'CVECountsByDate'

--Put your condition, if you want to filter the tables
--like '%TRN_%' and charindex('Archive',table_name) = 0 and charindex('ErrorLog',table_name) = 0
--Open the cursor and iterate till end
OPEN tableCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @tablename     

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @tablearchive =  @tablename+'_Archive'

    --check for the table exists, not, create it
    IF not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME= @tablearchive) 
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'select * into ' + @tablearchive +' from '+ @tablename +' where 1=2'
        EXEC(@sql)
    END

    --check the structure is same, if not, create it
    IF exists (select column_name from 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=@tablename and column_name not in (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            where TABLE_NAME=@tablearchive))
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'drop table ' + @tablearchive
        EXEC(@sql)

        SET @sql = 'select * into ' + @tablearchive +' from '+ @tablename +' where 1=2'
        EXEC(@sql)
    END

    --Check if the table contains, identify column,if yes, then it should be handled in different way
    --You cannot remove the identity column property through T-SQL
    --Since the structure of both tables are same, the insert fails, as it cannot insert the identity column
    --value in the archive table
    IF EXISTS(SELECT *      FROM information_schema.tables      WHERE table_name = @tablename AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME),
            'TableHasIdentity') != 0)
    BEGIN
        --Select the identity column name automatically             
        select @idname = column_name   
        from information_schema.columns 
        where columnproperty(object_id(table_name), column_name, 'isidentity') = 1 
          and table_name = @tablearchive

        --Remove the column
        SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tablearchive + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @idname
        EXEC(@sql)

        --Create the column name again (not as identity)
        --archive table does require identity column
        SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tablearchive + ' ADD ' + @idname+ ' INT'
        EXEC(@sql)
    END

    SET @sql = 'insert into ' + @tablearchive +' select * from '+ @tablename
    EXEC(@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @tablename 

    declare @PrevMonth nvarchar(MAX) = 'D' + cast(year(getdate()) as char(4)) + right('0' + cast(month(getdate())-1 as varchar), 2) + '__'
    DECLARE @DynSql nvarchar(MAX) = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tablename + ' DROP  COLUMNS IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT COLUMN_NAME Columns FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ' + @tablename + ' 
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE ' + @PrevMonth + ''

    SELECT (@DynSql)
    EXEC(@DynSql)
END

CLOSE tableCursor
DEALLOCATE tableCursor
```

So exactly how do I get the column removal part of my proc to work?

Comment: I think you should reconsider your approach to a solution where you dont have to mess with the schema every month. it all seems like a bad design to me.

Comment: I agree with @RicardoC. When you have to change the schema every month it is a very clear indicator that something is horribly wrong with your design. Databases are designed to hold data, not be manipulated like a puppet all the time.

Comment: That procedure is something I got from someone else. So you are recommending I leave all these columns in the main table? Are you aware that I am importing numerical records every day, over 3000? Trust me when I tell you, I considered very carefully just putting data in row by row, but the database table would become extremely large very quickly. My concern is referencing by CVE_Id number and then just placing the count in the date column. Unless any of you have a different schema idea.

Comment: 3k records per day/ 1m per year isn't a large amount of data.  Have you run into trouble, or are you pre-empting?  What edition of SQL Server are you running?  Anything above standard can partition tables, which might address your concerns.

Comment: My last comment may have come across as rude. Not my intention. The point I wanted to make is: if 3k records per day caused a problem it might be better to fix the underlying issue, rather than roll your own archive soliton.

Comment: Well, I am only trying to consider my users, I realize that 3K+ rows per day is not a huge amount of data, I guess maybe I am just looking for a way to keep the data in the current table slim and report on the history as a larger chunk. I suppose I could do this archival process by hand, I was only trying to automate it so I don't run the risk of forgetting; I never trust my memory for good reason.

Comment: And this is only a pre-emptive measure, I have had no problems yet. It is SQL Server 2014 so I know the actual database size is not an issue.

Comment: I figured it out, it was the way I was writing out the dynamic query, I forgot to surround the table name with quote marks, so SQL could not find the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query which apparently I stared at for way too long read:

```
ALTER TABLE CVECountsByDate DROP COLUMNS IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
Columns FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = CVECountsByDate AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'D201609__'
```

This should actually have output like this:

```
ALTER TABLE CVECountsByDate DROP COLUMNS IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
Columns FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CVECountsByDate' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'D201609__'
```

I forgot to surround the table name with quotation marks. And yes I have a red hand print in the middle of my forehead when it dawned on me.

So the query itself reads as follows:

```
    DECLARE @DynSql nvarchar(MAX) = 'ALTER TABLE CVECountsByDate DROP 
    COLUMNS IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME Columns FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '''CVECountsByDate''' AND 
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''' + @PrevYear + ''')'
```